# How to make all Contact 7 Fields the same size?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I have this [site](http://deilbeatz.com/), and I am having trouble with making all fields in contact form 7 to have the same size, like "Submit" button as example. I tried to insert this CSS that I found somewhere, but don't make any changes.

```
.wpcf7-form {
max-width: 750px;
margin: auto;
}
```

How to make all fields in Contact form in my page the same height and width? Thanks

Comment: If you are wanting to have your fields the same width, you would need to modify the `input` tag -or- create a class that has `width: 100%;` and add that class to your input element via html.  There are several ways to do this.  Could you provide your css and html file(s) so we have a better idea of what you have rather than providing a link to your website?  That one class you provided does not help in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i saw in your linked site that it is not getting full width because of your label tag. following css will help you to get same width.

```
form.wpcf7-form label {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps.